# Why is plt.imsave() giving me an type error: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float while using tensorflow to reshape my kernel?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib

I can't understand why matplotlib is giving me a type error: 
`TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float`

Thanks in advance to anyone who can answer my doubt.

If code is not clear in this post you can go to this repositry and download it -
[Code](https://github.com/rajcivils/Cats-Dataset/blob/master/Code.py)

If needed you can use the dataset to give me a solution - [Dataset](https://github.com/rajcivils/Cats-Dataset/tree/master/cats)

Also download this file - [libs](https://github.com/rajcivils/Cats-Dataset/tree/master/libs)

The functions needed -

```
def gauss2d(mean, stddev, ksize):
    z = gauss(mean, stddev, ksize)
    g = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=g):
        z_2d = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(z, [ksize, 1]), tf.reshape(z, [1, ksize]))
        return z_2d.eval()


def convolve(img, kernel):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=g):
        convolved = tf.nn.conv2d(img, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        res = convolved.eval()
    return res


def gabor(ksize=32):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=g):
        z_2d = gauss2d(0.0, 1.0, ksize)
        ones = tf.ones((1, ksize))
        ys = tf.sin(tf.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, ksize))
        ys = tf.reshape(ys, [ksize, 1])
        wave = tf.matmul(ys, ones)
        gabor = tf.multiply(wave, z_2d)
        return gabor.eval()
```

**My Code -**

```
kernel = np.concatenate([gabor(ksize)[:, :, np.newaxis] for i in range(3)], axis=2)

# Now make the kernels into the shape: [ksize, ksize, 3, 1]:
kernel_4d = tf.reshape(kernel, [3, 3, 3, 1])
assert(kernel_4d.shape == (ksize, ksize, 3, 1))

sess = tf.Session()
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.imshow(sess.run(kernel_4d[:, :, 0, 0]), cmap='gray')
plt.imsave(arr=kernel_4d[:, :, 0, 0], fname='kernel.png', cmap='gray')
```

I know there are many questions like this on stackoverflow but none of them are solving my problem. I tried to decrease and increase the dimensions but it didn't work. I even tried to convert into a numpy array that also didn't work, I even converted it to a normal python list

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh eureka! I got it I didn't run it in a session while saving the image that was the problem. I just posted this answer for anyone who got stuck over this problem -

```
kernel = np.concatenate([gabor(ksize)[:, :, np.newaxis] for i in range(3)], axis=2)

# Now make the kernels into the shape: [ksize, ksize, 3, 1]:
kernel_4d = tf.reshape(kernel, [3, 3, 3, 1])
assert(kernel_4d.shape == (ksize, ksize, 3, 1))

sess = tf.Session()
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.imshow(sess.run(kernel_4d[:, :, 0, 0]), cmap='gray')
# added sess.run() to kernel↓
plt.imsave(arr=sess.run(kernel_4d[:, :, 0, 0]), fname='kernel.png', cmap='gray')
```